# Listen to multiple sockets (different ports) on local machine

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am about to write a client, listing on different ports for incoming UDP packets. But the problem is, I do not know on which `DatagramSocket(in_port)` the next packet will arrive. And I do not want to have, e.g. four threads running, each of them listening specifically to only one `DatagramSocket`.

Mu question: Is there a way to use something like the `select` function in `C` where I just have to pass a set of file descriptors and `select` loops through all of them to return the one, where a packet was received?

Also a code example would be very good to have.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "And I do not want to have, e.g. four threads running". why not?

Comment: hmm, of course would be the easiest way, right. But I thought there could be something more elegant... But if there isn't, I would just go for that approach.

Comment: See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html

Comment: @assylias for the same reason you wouldn't want e.g. ten thousand threads running once you've got that many ports.